# How Do I loop this arrays to extract only the orderTotal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, object

How would I loop this array and ADD the orderTotal field inside the Item object? (0) OrderTotal  $100 (1) OrderTotal  $220

```
var sum = 320;
```

save the Sum of both OrderTotal field to a variable

My goal is to get a Sum of all my order total fields

```
[
    {
        "itemID": "C619D69C-970D-11E7-AFD4-E44BB50029CC",
        "itemType": "Job",
        "item": {
        "jobColor": "18, 2, 218",
        "jobType": "Work",
        "employeeIDs": [
            "af879a7d-1aec-e111-834a-002590274606"
        ],
        "note": "",
        "jobStatus": "Scheduled",
        "actualDateTimeStart": "9/13/2017 11:00 AM",
        "orderTotal**": 100,
        "orderRefNumber": "",
        "orderNumber": 8375,
        "orderType": "Estimate",
        "siteID": "56f6f468-957c-11e7-b464-b4bf180545bb"
    }
},
{
    "itemID": "F9CF5384-9244-11E7-9BCA-E81C6A1CA1CB",
    "itemType": "Job",
    "item": {
        "jobColor": "255, 126, 0",
        "jobType": "Work",
        "employeeIDs": [
            "af879a7d-1aec-e111-834a-002590274606"
        ],
        "note": "",
        "jobStatus": "Scheduled",
        "actualDateTimeStart": "9/13/2017 2:00 PM",
        "orderGroup": "",
        "orderTotal": 220,
        "orderRefNumber": "",
        "orderNumber": 8367,
        "orderType": "Work Order",
        "siteID": "7e131f90-6657-11e7-8416-875831a581c3"
    }
```

Comment: had you have a look to [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)?

Answer (score 1):

you can reduce the array like this:

```
const sum = orders.reduce((acc, order) => acc + order.orderTotal, 0);
```

Comment: Does it matter if this is a response from an API?

Comment: no, as long as what you reduce is an array it's fine

Comment: Duplicate answer, only by 2 mins, clearly unintentional

Comment: @BrunoPaula Why would that matter? Data is data, it doesn't matter where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = myArray.reduce((sum, current) => sum + current.orderTotal, 0);
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some additional info regarding **how** your code solves the problem at hand. Doing so aids those with similar (but not identical) problems. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) to extract all the orderTotal.

ANd then, use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) to sum all the orderTotal.

```js
const array = [{
    "itemID": "C619D69C-970D-11E7-AFD4-E44BB50029CC",
    "itemType": "Job",
    "item": {
      "jobColor": "18, 2, 218",
      "jobType": "Work",
      "employeeIDs": [
        "af879a7d-1aec-e111-834a-002590274606"
      ],
      "note": "",
      "jobStatus": "Scheduled",
      "actualDateTimeStart": "9/13/2017 11:00 AM",
      "orderTotal": 100,
      "orderRefNumber": "",
      "orderNumber": 8375,
      "orderType": "Estimate",
      "siteID": "56f6f468-957c-11e7-b464-b4bf180545bb"
    }
  },
  {
    "itemID": "F9CF5384-9244-11E7-9BCA-E81C6A1CA1CB",
    "itemType": "Job",
    "item": {
      "jobColor": "255, 126, 0",
      "jobType": "Work",
      "employeeIDs": [
        "af879a7d-1aec-e111-834a-002590274606"
      ],
      "note": "",
      "jobStatus": "Scheduled",
      "actualDateTimeStart": "9/13/2017 2:00 PM",
      "orderGroup": "",
      "orderTotal": 220,
      "orderRefNumber": "",
      "orderNumber": 8367,
      "orderType": "Work Order",
      "siteID": "7e131f90-6657-11e7-8416-875831a581c3"
    }
  }
];
console.log('map result ', array.map(item => item.item.orderTotal));
console.log('reduce on map result ', array.map(item => item.item.orderTotal).reduce((item1, item2) => (item1 + item2)));
```

Comment: Does it matter if this is a response from an API?

Comment: #reduce exists since es5.1 and is IE9 compatible. It matters only if you want an IE <9 compatibility (but who wants it anymore today ? ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) statement to trace this array.
Go through the demo below.

```js
var array=[
          {
            "itemID": "C619D69C-970D-11E7-AFD4-E44BB50029CC",
            "itemType": "Job",
            "item": {
              "jobColor": "18, 2, 218",
              "jobType": "Work",
              "employeeIDs": [
                "af879a7d-1aec-e111-834a-002590274606"
              ],
              "note": "",
              "jobStatus": "Scheduled",
              "actualDateTimeStart": "9/13/2017 11:00 AM",
              "orderTotal": 100,
              "orderRefNumber": "",
              "orderNumber": 8375,
              "orderType": "Estimate",
              "siteID": "56f6f468-957c-11e7-b464-b4bf180545bb"
            }
          },
          {
            "itemID": "F9CF5384-9244-11E7-9BCA-E81C6A1CA1CB",
            "itemType": "Job",
            "item": {
              "jobColor": "255, 126, 0",
              "jobType": "Work",
              "employeeIDs": [
                "af879a7d-1aec-e111-834a-002590274606"
              ],
              "note": "",
              "jobStatus": "Scheduled",
              "actualDateTimeStart": "9/13/2017 2:00 PM",
              "orderGroup": "",
              "orderTotal": 220,
              "orderRefNumber": "",
              "orderNumber": 8367,
              "orderType": "Work Order",
              "siteID": "7e131f90-6657-11e7-8416-875831a581c3"
            }
            }];
  var sum=0;
$.each( array, function( key, itemData ) {
  console.log("orderTotal: "+ itemData.item.orderTotal);
  sum+=itemData.item.orderTotal;
});
 console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is this is your expected output?